# Mutlithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I read online that modern chips are multi threaded (ie, each core would have a couple of threads). And then I also read about the GIL in python, which ensure only one thread runs at any point in time.

Does it mean, even when we have a multithreaded core, python programming would not be able to run multiple threads simultaneously? Or is there a way to achieve this

Comment: Correct. Only one thread can execute Python bytecodes at any one time. Use _multiprocessing_ to get around this, to improve performance of an IO bound program. There are plenty of free articles and videos online that discuss this issue in depth.

Comment: "Simultaneous," is an ambiguous word. Python threads can run [_concurrently_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing), but the GIL prevents them from being usable for [_parallel processing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve multithreading in the same way it  is possible in other languages due to the GIL. You can bypass this in a few ways.

The library "Multiprocessing" spawns a new process to execute with a copy of the python interpreter. This allows you to achieve concurrency but is pretty expensive and not exactly multithreading.

[Jython](https://www.jython.org/) which is a python, but written in Java. Similar to Cython, it has a few different features, one of which is the absence of a GIL.

Answer (score -1):

The operating system is capable of handling multiple processes concurrently. It allocates a separate memory space to each process, so that one process cannot access or write anything other's space. A thread on the other hand can be thought of as a light-weight sub-process in a single program. Threads of a single program share the memory space allocated to it.

Multiple threads within a process share the same data space with the main thread and can therefore share information or communicate with each other more easily than if they were separate processes.

Comment: I think the original poster was wondering about python, not about "what threading is"